# Update progress bar from Task.Run async

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method to generate software activation key from User Information:

```
private async void GenerateAsync()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var secretstring = "CustomerName >> " + txtFullname.Text + " >> " + txtproducid.Text;
                keymng = new KeyManager(secretstring);
                var dateexp = numExpdate.Value;
                if (dateexp == 0)
                {
                    dateexp = 730000;
                }

                if (cbLicenseType.SelectedIndex == 0)
                {
                    kvc = new KeyValueClass()
                    {
                        LicenseType = LicenseType.FULL,
                        Header = Convert.ToByte(9),
                        Footer = Convert.ToByte(6),
                        ProductCode = PRODUCTCODE,
                        Edition = (Edition)Enum.Parse(typeof(Edition), cbEdition.SelectedText),
                        Version = 1,
                        Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(dateexp))
                    };

                    if (!keymng.GenerateKey(kvc, ref productkey))
                    {
                        //Handling Error
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    kvc = new KeyValueClass()
                    {
                        LicenseType = LicenseType.TRIAL,
                        Header = Convert.ToByte(9),
                        Footer = Convert.ToByte(6),
                        ProductCode = PRODUCTCODE,
                        Edition = (Edition)Enum.Parse(typeof(Edition), cbEdition.SelectedText),
                        Version = 1,
                        Expiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToInt32(dateexp))
                    };
                    if (!keymng.GenerateKey(kvc, ref productkey))
                    {
                        //Handling Error
                    }
                }
            });

        }
```

and I have progressbar. I want to run this method async and update progress to progressbar. How to update UI with async-await method. BackgroundWorker is  alternative???

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use the more modern `IProgress<T>`/`Progress<T>` types:

```
var progress = new Progress<int>(value => { progressBar.Value = value; });
await Task.Run(() => GenerateAsync(progress));

void GenerateAsync(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  ...
  progress?.Report(13);
  ...
}
```

This is better than `Invoke` because it doesn't tie your business logic (`GenerateAsync`) to a particular UI, or to any UI at all.

Comment: I'm getting that Report doesn't exist... -_-

Have to do IProgress<int> progress = ...  then your code

Comment: Yes, it has to be typed as `IProgress<T>`. If you pass it as a method argument like my code does, then it should work fine.

Answer (score 6):

I use this method in Winforms:

```
progressBar1.Invoke((Action)(() => progressBar1.Value=50))
```

Comment: Good answer while I am not sure if you need to cast it to an action. Should be possible like this `progressBar1.Invoke(() => 
                    { 
                        progressBar1.Value = 50 
                    });`

Comment: @Nico Cool, I'll try without the cast

Comment: Nice answer! I'll try it.

Comment: Let me know if it is not possible @BaliC :) Didn't work with c# for quite a while by now.